# Magento SavePayment() Throws Exception

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, payment-methods

I am using one page checkout method.When I place order externally it throws me a

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message
'The requested Payment Method is not available.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\restaurant\app\Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\restaurant\app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Quote\Payment.php(153):  Mage::throwException('The requested P...')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\restaurant\app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Model\Type\Onepage.php(631): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Payment->importData(Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\restaurant\placeorder.php(22): Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->savePayment(Array)
#3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\restaurant\app\Mage.php on line 595`
```

I also enabled the payment methods at admin.

My code is,

```
<?php 
require_once 'app/Mage.php';

Mage::app();

$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

$checkout = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage');

$checkout->initCheckout();

$checkout->saveCheckoutMethod('register');

$checkout->saveShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate');

$checkout->savePayment(array('method'=>'cashondelivery'));

try {
    $checkout->saveOrder();
}
catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}           

$cart->truncate();
$cart->save();
$cart->getItems()->clear()->save();     

Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->logout();
?>
```

I have seen some of discussion regarding the issue..but its not working..
I hope someone will help on this issue...

Comment: please check cod is enable from admin?

Comment: yes its enabled @AmitBera

Comment: please checkout with details from magento frontend system.Please let me know there ,cod is enable or not?

Comment: Yes,cod is at checkout page@AmitBera

Comment: i think there is issue on store id try to set as Mage::app()->getStore('default')->getId() @Astro

Comment: same error @KeyurShah

Comment: I think you need to set customer as well.

Comment: yes...I think so...@AdarshKhatri